# how to hide asp.net login control 's Remember me checkbox and Remember me text in code behind based on a condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

I am trying to hide Remember me checkbox on page load event based on a value of a parameter. If the value of parameter is true , the checkbox and Remember me next time text is displayed otherwise it should be hidden from the page. I am using the layout template of the asp.net login control. I have tried using display :none on the checkboxstyle but the checkbox gets hidden only when this is done in aspx page . I have set Display Remember me = false, REmember me text = "" , nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you post the code when you use Display.RememberMe property?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys and sorry for not posting the code. I figured it out.
CheckBox cek = (CheckBox)Login1.FindControl("RememberMe");
cek.Visible=false;

is the solution which hides the checkbox and its text from codebehind. Good luck